# How to copy one row and paste as a column with repetition?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I transform my datatable from image 1 to image 2 using data.table function?
[image: mydatatable image 1]
[image: newdatatable image 2]

Sorry, I couldn't write datatable with accurate codes.

Comment: Have you searched this site? There must be dozens of questions on melting data.tables.

Comment: Yes, I did. But I couldn't find like my case. I'm new in R programming so I am not be able to write code easily.

Comment: The FAQ on transforming data from wide to long shows many methods. If you need more help than that, please both (a) give us some sample data to test on---we can't demonstrate solutions on pictures, and (b) show what you tried, so we can meet you where you are and correct any misconceptions. If you need help with (a), see the [FAQ on reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The easiest way to share a bit of data in a copy/pasteable way is `dput`, like `dput(your_data[1:5, 1:7])` for the first 5 rows of the first 7 columns.

Comment: One other minor comment: save mentions of `RStudio` to cases where the editor matters---like if you have code that doesn't run in RStudio but does run on the command line or in the default R GUI.

Comment: Okey, thank you so much for your comments. I will pay attention to them.

Comment: use 'dplyr' package and melt your dataset to long format